# Django Wagtail Page.objects.descendant_of(inclusive=False) Error

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using Django 2.0 with the latest version of Wagtail CMS.
I am pretty new to Wagtail and I am trying to query the children of EventIndexPage which is EventPage and have them appear on my HomePage.

I am trying to use this line of python in home app models.py below:

```
special_events = EventIndexPage.objects.descendant_of(inclusive=False)
```

But It returns:

```
 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: descendant_of() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

When I try putting "EventPage" in before "inclusive=false" I get a type error because its an array not an integer.

docs: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html

**Models.py of the home app:**

```
from django.db import models
from event.models import EventIndexPage

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    special_events = EventIndexPage.objects.descendant_of(inclusive=False)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

**Models.py of event app**

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.search import index

class EventIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full")
    ]


class EventPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, this line of code is in the wrong place - putting it immediately within `class HomePage(Page):` means that your query will be run once at server startup, and the results will become part of the definition of `HomePage`. You probably want to make it a method of `HomePage` instead, so that you can re-run the query on every page load:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def special_events(self):
        return EventIndexPage.objects.descendant_of...
```

Now let's look at what `descendant_of` is doing. `EventIndexPage.objects.descendant_of(other_page)` means "find all of the `EventIndexPage` pages which are descendants (i.e. immediate children, or grandchildren, and so on) of `other_page`". Since you're actually looking for `EventPage` pages, not `EventIndexPage`, you should use `EventPage.objects.descendant_of`.

Now, we need to supply `other_page` - i.e. tell it *which* page they need to be descendants of. You might try `EventPage.objects.descendant_of(EventIndexPage)`, but this won't work because `EventIndexPage` is a page *type* - there could potentially be several `EventIndexPage`s on your site, and `descendant_of` needs to be given one specific page instance. If you're sure you're only ever going to have one `EventIndexPage` on your site, you can use `EventIndexPage.objects.first()` to tell it "use the first `EventIndexPage` that you encounter", which makes the final function:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def special_events(self):
        event_index_page = EventIndexPage.objects.first()
        return EventPage.objects.descendant_of(event_index_page)
```

You can safely disregard the `inclusive` option here: that just determines whether a page is considered to be a descendant of itself, i.e. whether the results of `descendant_of(other_page)` can include `other_page`. In this case, the `EventPage.objects.descendant_of(event_index_page)` results will never include `event_index_page`, because `event_index_page` is not an `EventPage`.

One last suggestion, though: do you actually need to deal with the `EventIndexPage` at all? Presumably you're not planning to have `EventPage`s that exist outside of the `EventIndexPage`, in which case it doesn't matter whether your query says "give me all `EventPage`s that are descendants of `EventIndexPage`" or "give me all `EventPage`s regardless of where they exist". If so, the function can become simply:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def special_events(self):
        return EventPage.objects.all()
```

Or, if you're applying this condition because you intend to have multiple sub-sites each with their own `EventPageIndex` and set of events, and only want to return events for the current sub-site, you could take advantage of the fact that the events in question are *also* descendants of the current homepage (i.e. `self`) as well as being descendants of the `EventPageIndex`:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    def special_events(self):
        return EventPage.objects.descendant_of(self)
```

Comment: Wow Thank you! I wish I could give you more points. This really cleared things up.

Comment: How would I go about actually getting that method to execute? A hook.register or page_publish signal?

Comment: Just access it as the point where you want to output the list on your template: `{% for event in page.special_events %}`

Comment: Got it, Thanks. Is there a place I can look at common Wagtail template examples?